# Meaning of two cointegrating vectors in a VECM

Tags: time-series, multivariate-analysis, cointegration, vector-error-correction-model

Given three I(1) time series, what does it mean to have 2 cointegrating vectors inside the error correction term?
As mentioned in the below image, cant we merge `ec1t-1` and `ec2t-1` in a single ec term since it will just be like a sum of coefficients

Also, what is the significance of the constant term inside the cointegration vector, and how does it make a difference if we put that outside the vector?
[image]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a vector error correction (VECM) model
$$
\Delta y_t=\Pi y_{t-1}+\Gamma_1\Delta y_{t-1}+...+\Gamma_{p-1}\Delta y_{t-(p-1)}+\varepsilon_t
$$
where $y_t=(y_{1,t},y_{2,t},y_{3,t})^\top$ and $\Pi=\alpha^\top\beta$. The error correction terms contained in $\beta$ get premultiplied by a different vector $\alpha_j$ for $j=1,\ 2,\ 3$ in each of the three equations (for $\Delta y_{1,t}$, for $\Delta y_{2,t}$ and for $\Delta y_{3,t}$). If all the $\alpha$s were equal ($\alpha_1=\alpha_2=\alpha_3$), we could do as you suggest, but usually they are not equal, so we have to maintain all $\alpha$ and $\beta$s separately.

What does it mean to have 2 cointegrating vectors inside the error correction term? It means there are two linearly independent linear combinations of variables that are $I(0)$. Thus, there is only one stochastic trend behind $y_{1,t}$, $y_{2,t}$ and $y_{3,t}$.

Comment: Thanks @Richard Hardy
Also, what is the significance of the constant term inside the cointegration vector, and how does it make a difference if we put that outside the vector?

Comment: @vvvsss, is there a constant term inside the vector?

Comment: Yes,
i.e. its a part of ect-1
And what would be the implications if I pull that out of the error correction term and make it a part of the main equation?

Comment: @vvvsss, could you post this as a separate question? And in it, could you show explicitly that the constant term is there (citing some reference or output from a computer program)?